# ruby koans about_nil.rb -- question fr/ newbie

Tags: ruby, exception

I'm an **absolute beginner** in programming. I am gravitating to ruby and have set up the koans. The section begins with:

```
def test_you_dont_get_null_pointer_errors_when_calling_methods_on_nil
```

Please explain this line:

```
rescue Exception => ex
```

I've figured out the first two koans in this section.

Comment: This is called "exception handling."  Try checking Wikipedia on that.  Voting to close your question as "general reference".

Comment: @Pavel +1 General reference: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html

Answer (score 2):

That line states, rescues the code within the begin-rescue block whenever it throws an Exception with type [`Exception`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Exception.html). It just so turns out that Exception is the top level exception that all other exceptions inherit from(Such as syntax error, No method error etc). Because of this, all exceptions will be rescued. It then stores that exception instance in the variable `ex` in which you can look at further(such as the backtrace, message etc).

[I'd read this guide on Ruby Exceptions](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html).

An example would be this:

```
begin
    hey "hi"
rescue Exception => ex
  puts ex.message
end
#=> Prints undefined method `hey' for main:Object
```

However, if the code within the begin block gives no error, it will not go down the rescue branch.

```
begin
    puts "hi"
rescue Exception => ex
  puts "ERROR!"
end
#=> Prints "hi", and does not print ERROR!
```

Comment: thank you Mike I understood part of your answer with relief. john

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the comment at the [start of the method?](https://github.com/rizwanreza/ruby_koans/blob/master/koans/about_nil.rb)

```
  def test_you_dont_get_null_pointer_errors_when_calling_methods_on_nil
    # What happens when you call a method that doesn't exist. The
    # following begin/rescue/end code block captures the exception and
    # make some assertions about it.
    begin
      nil.some_method_nil_doesnt_know_about
    rescue Exception => ex
      # What exception has been caught?
      assert_equal NoMethodError, ex.class

      # What message was attached to the exception?
      # (HINT: replace __ with part of the error message.)
      assert_match(/undefined method/, ex.message)
    end
  end
```